# Quick sort algorithm to sort the array by using the Hoare Partitioning in Java

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm trying to sort this array by quick sort:

```
int[] arr = {25,23,21,29,28,22,24,27};
```

My quick sort function:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr) { // sorts array using quick sort algorithm
    if (arr[0] < arr[arr.length-1]) {
        int s = hoarePartitioning(arr);
        quickSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, s-1));
        quickSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, s+1, arr.length));
    }
}
```

I used Hoare Partitioning:

```
public static int hoarePartitioning(int[] arr) {
    int pivot = arr[0];
    int i = 0;
    int j = arr.length;
    do {
        do {i++;} while(pivot >= arr[i] && i < arr.length);
        do {j--;} while(pivot <= arr[j] && j >= 0);
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }while(i <= j);

    int temp = arr[i];  //undo last swap when i >= j
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;

    temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;

    return j;
}
```

However, when I print out the array, this is the result:

```
22 23 21 24 25 28 29 27
```

My Hoare Partitioning function works fine but I still don't understand why the array is not sorted. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `quicksort` method is fundamentally wrong:

```
    quickSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, s-1));
    quickSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, s+1, arr.length));
```

Each time you recurse, you create a new arrays for the left and right subarrays, (try to) sort the new arrays, and then **throw them away**.  Net result: the original array does not change.

Don't copy the subarrays.  Pass the original array, along with the start and end of the subarray to be sorted in each recursive call.  If necessary use an auxiliary function; e.g.

```
 public void quicksort(int[] array) {
     quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
 }

 public void quicksort(int[] array, int start, int end) {
     ...
 }
```

There are some other problems too:

1. The `if` test looks wrong.  Why would you skip sorting the array / subarray in that condition?   The actual test should be on the size of subarray that is being sorted ... not the subarray contents.
2. The upper bounds calculations for the subarray look wrong; `s - 1` is an inclusive bound, but `arr.length` is an exclusive bound.  One of them must be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion. However,  when I debug, both subarrays seem correct for my bounds.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Which "first suggestion" are you referring to?  The main problem or "other problem" #1?

Answer (score 0):

Generic Hoare partition code as a single function. Using the middle value for pivot avoids worst case O(n^2) time complexity for already sorted or reverse sorted data. Any element except a[hi] can be used as the pivot with this specific code. There is no need to bounds check the indexes, because worst case, reaching the pivot will stop the initial inner loops, and any swap will allow the inner loops to be repeated without bounds check.

```
    public static void qsort(int[] a, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if(lo >= hi)
            return;
        int  p = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
        int  i = lo-1;
        int  j = hi+1;
        int t;
        while(true){
            while(a[++i] < p);
            while(a[--j] > p);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            t     = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = t;
        }
        qsort(a, lo, j);
        qsort(a, j+1, hi);
    }
```